# How to loop a service object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made the code to be super simple

Assume that when I call `Class.new(object).call` it will return a response.

The goal is simple

I want to loop a service for example,

*/service/update_many_post.rb*

```
class UpdateManyPost

   def call
     posts.each do |post|
       UpdateAPost.new(post: post).call
     end
   end

   private

   def posts
     Post.all
   end
end
```

*/service/update_a_post.rb*

```
class UpdateAPost
       def initialize(post:)
          @post = post
       end

       def call
          @post.title = "I am great"
          @post.save
       end
  end
```

I want to call rake task

```
UpdateManyPost.new.call do |response|
   # but seems like when i do, Nothing is return from the call.
   Rails.logger.info(response)

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your current rake task code doesn't seem to return anything is that your `UpdateManyPost.new.call` method doesn't take a block. It is being called, but your block with `response` isn't being used at all.

For the rake task code to work as you have it, you'll want `UpdateManyPost#call` to take a block argument, and iterate over each `post` in `posts`, yielding the response of running `UpdateAPost#call`:

```
# service/update_many_post.rb
class UpdateManyPost
  def call(&block)
    posts.each do |post|
      response = UpdateAPost.new(post: post).call
      yield response
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

Even better would be to use `posts.find_each`, a batching utility that ActiveRecord gives you, that automatically pages the query using LIMIT and OFFSET to only load 1,000 results into memory at a time. It is essentially interchangeable with `posts.each`; it will iterate through all results, it just automatically handles the batching for you.

Comment: yielding each response would be a better option IMO. This makes the response disposable rather than returning an entire array which could consume large amounts of memory

Comment: You're correct, @engineersmnky. Thanks for chiming in again, I keep seeing you around here :). My goal was to simply address the issue of trying to pass a block directly to the `call`. The fact that `UpdateManyPost` pulls in all records at once is even more of a potential memory issue since AcitveRecord objects are huge. If I were worried about memory, I would batch it using `find_each` to begin with

Comment: Yeah I hang around; although you will find me more in the comments section because unless I disagree with all the answers provided I feel that adding answers with minute changes just clutters up a post. (The reputation points or whatever they are called really doesn't mean that much to me)

Comment: @rmhunter how to batch it?

Comment: @airsoftFreak I updated my answer completely. I believe now it actually answers the implementation you were looking for, and is inspired by @engineersmnky 's point that yielding is the best way to handle memory properly. I also added a comment at the end about how to use `find_each` for batching.

Comment: Should i do `UpdateManyPost.new.call do |response|` or `UpdateManyPost.new.call.each do |response|`  I believe you have removed the rake part. Thanks

Comment: You can keep the rake task how you have it in your question. My update makes it so that `.call` will call `each` under the hood and yield the results, so the block in your rake task will execute once for each `post`, and the `response` in your block will be the result of calling `UpdateAPost#call`.

Comment: I have another question, it is related to this question. How would i write a spec for this Service. You can answer it if you have time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62457656/how-to-check-array-changes-in-rspec-after-a-service-call . Thanks @rmhunter

Comment: @rmhunter how do i test that please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62463856/localjumperror-no-block-given-yield

Comment: @rmhunter how do i test yield in this use case. I keep getting error. you can take a look at the question.

Comment: @engineersmnky do you how to solve this issue? there's a 100 bounty points attached to the question. thanks

Comment: @airsoftFreak sorry I was away from my computer for the weekend. I will take a look at that other question. Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer? Is it no longer correct? I'm happy to update if needed to be accepted again so others can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

In your rake task, try this...

```
response = UpdateManyPost.new.call
Rails.logger.info(response)
```

Instead of iterating over the posts, and updating each one, you can utilize the `update_all` method provided by ActiveRecord.

```
class UpdateManyPost

   def call
     posts.update_all(title: "I am great")
   end

   private

   def posts
     Post.all
   end
end
```

Comment: The data did change. The goal is to return a response for each call to `UpdateAPost`.

Comment: Updated my answer. I think you would get an array of boolean values from `UpdateManyPost.new.call`