# how to check array changes in rspec after a service call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

The goal is simple

example we have an array

```
[
  {name: "ghost", state: "rejected"}, 
  {name: "donkey", state: "rejected"}
]
```

After running the Service call `UpdateAllUsers`, it would change all the users to `'accepted'`

```
   [
      {name: "ghost", state: "accepted"}, 
      {name: "donkey", state: "accepted"}
    ]
```

The question here is how do i check all the object in the array to have the same value after that service call in rspec?

example in rspec

```
describe 'call' do
   let(:all_users) { build(:users, 2, state: "rejected")

    service_call { UpdateAllUsers.new.call }


    it "change all user state to approved" do
         # The goal is to check all the users state after the Service call.
         # Can't find a way to do so
         # the after state should be state => 'accepted'
     end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

May be is too late but it could be useful if someone stumble with the same problem.

```rb
describe 'call' do
   let(:all_users) { build(:users, 2, state: "rejected")

    service_call { UpdateAllUsers.new.call }


    it "change all user state to approved" do
         # The goal is to check all the users state after the Service call.
         # Can't find a way to do so
         # the after state should be state => 'accepted'
        all_users.each do |user|
          expect(user).to include(:state => 'accepted')
        end
    end
end
```